# Disable ng-click in parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have next html:

```
<div class="parent"
         ng-click="ParentClick()">
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="child" ng-click="ChildClick()">
       Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

So, when I click on `Some Text`, I have two method calls: `ParentClick(), ChildClick()`. Is it possible to disable `ParentClick()` event when I clicking on `Some Text`, in CSS way?

Answer (score 7):

When clicking on the `ChildClick()` you want to run `event.stopPropagation()` in order to prevent the `click` event to bubble up the DOM tree

```
function ChildClick() {
    event.stopPropagation()
    ....
}
```

In case you have the `ChildClick` function part of the `$scope` you can pass the `$event` to the function and use it inside:

```
<div class="child" ng-click="ChildClick($event)">
</div>

$scope.ChildClick = function ($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

pass `$event` to the inner div ng-click `ng-click="ChildClick($event)"`, add an argument (say `$event`) to the `ChildClick` function and call `$event.stopPropagation()` there to stop bubbling up.